# Autoit - nested arrays

Tags: arrays, variable-assignment, autoit

I'm trying to access a value in a nested array in Autoit, but I'm getting the out of range error message.
This is my code:

```
Func ThisFunction()
  local $one[6] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  local $two[6] = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

  local $combined[2] = [$one, $two]

  For $i = 0 to UBound($combined)-1
    $result = SomeFunction ( $combined[$i] )
    If $result Then
      return $combined[$i][0]
    EndIf
  Next
EndFunc
```

Is there a way to access/return a specific index from the nested $combined array?

EDIT: I found a working solution, I don't know if it's good practice

```
  For $i = 0 to UBound($combined)-1
    $result = SomeFunction ( $combined[$i] )
    If $result Then
      local $temp = $combined[$i]
      If IsArray($temp) Then
        return $temp[0]
      EndIf
    EndIf
  Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For $i = 0 to UBound($combined)-1
    $result = SomeFunction ( $combined[$i] )
    If $result Then
      local $temp = $combined[$i]
      If IsArray($temp) Then
        return $temp[0]
      EndIf
    EndIf
  Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you treat the $combined as a 2 dimension array. But it's a 1 dimensional array. (in your return).

try $one[$combined[$i]]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work out for me. I found another solution though.

Comment: Could you then please share your solution as an answer to your own question for others having a similar one? Unanswered questions (not marked as answered) lead to unnecessary effort. Thank you!